# How to configure and run hadoop cluster on LVM(Logical Volume Manager)

Tags: 12.04, lvm

Well i am new to the concepts of LVM(Local Volume Manager) and have create volumes in Ubuntu

Actually I am using windows and putty.Now i have also created LVM in that putty.

My question is whether it is possible to configure and run hadoop cluster in LVM(Logical Volume Manager) and if yes how to do it

Answer (score -1):

check this one, it looks lvm can help avoid some maintenance hassle with trade-off some performance

http://nicktj.tumblr.com/post/10201994102/hadoop-on-lvm2